# Delete rows with duplicated record in two different columns

Tags: r, syntax, subset

I would like to delete rows which contain the same string in collumn `C1` and `C3`:

My `df` input:

```
C1       C2      C3
14-130n  NE03   14-130n
23-401n  NE05   21-130n
43-123n  NE04   43-121n
```

My `final`expected output:

```
C1       C2      C3
23-401n  NE05   21-130n
43-123n  NE04   43-121n
```

I had tried  `final <- df[!(df[,1] = df[,3]),]`, but do not works. Some ideas? Cheers!

Comment: `=` wont work.. You need `==`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example:

```
df[!df$C1==df$C3,]
```

Where df:

```
df <- read.table(text='C1       C2      C3
14-130n  NE03   14-130n
23-401n  NE05   21-130n
43-123n  NE04   43-121n',header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

In case you have factors you should coerce to character before:

```
 df[as.character(df$C1)!=as.character(df$C3),]
```

Answer (score 2):

Would `final <- subset(df, C1!=C3)` serve the purpose?

Comment: a `for` loop also can "serve the purpose". The question is not only "what" but also "how". See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset) for referance